# Mean Square Displacement calculation using FFT

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, fft

For my array of temperature fluctuations (five million data points as `(time, temperature fluctuation)` I calculate Mean Square Displacement:

```
data = np.loadtxt("daily_temp.csv", skiprows = 0, delimiter = ",")
fluctuation = data[:, 3] #This is the temperature fluctuation column
z = len(fluctuation)
t = [np.log(i) for i in range(1, z+1)]
MSD = [i for i in range(z)]
for j in range(z, 0, -1):
    n = [i for i in range(j)]
    for i in range(j):
        a = fluctuation[i]
        b = fluctuation[i+z-j]
        c = (a-b)**2
        n[i] = c
    x = sum(n) / j
    print(j)
    MSD[z - j -1] = np.log10(x)
```

I took the logarithm because I want a log-log plot of temperature fluctuation vs time. [Here](https://github.com/hadim/Public-Notebooks/blob/master/Code/Quick_MSD/notebook.ipynb) is an FFT-based algorithm calculating MSD. I have no understanding on `S1` and `S2` under the `msd_fft` function. How to modify the code so it is FFT-based?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/34222273/4601890?